# cURL works for my REST API but Guzzle not

Tags: php, rest, curl, laravel-4, guzzle

I am trying to connect my Laravel framework to my server using Guzzle. Every GET request without parameters but I have problems with POST.

This request using cURL works fine:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"email":"user@domain.com", "pwd":"xxxxxx"}' http://www.example.com:1234/rest/user/validate
```

And this is what I have tried to implement with Guzzle:

```
$response = GuzzleHttp\post('http://www.example.com:1234/rest/user/validat', [
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
            'body'    => ['{"email":"user@domain.com", "pwd":"xxxxxx"}']
]);     
print_r($response->json());
```

When I make the request, I get the next error:

```
[status code] 415 [reason phrase] Unsupported Media Type
```

I think is something related to `body` but I don't know how to solve it.

Any idea?

Comment: Try leaving out the square brackets for the `body` value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no need to have the square brackets around the `body` value. Also, make sure there is an `Accept` header defined. You should use this instead:

```
$response = GuzzleHttp\post('http://www.example.com:1234/rest/user/validat', [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'],
        'body'    => '{"email":"user@domain.com", "pwd":"xxxxxx"}'
]);     
print_r($response->json());
```

Comment: While the json-format did not work (I used an array for body) this made it work for me, after many tries, thanks.

Comment: is there any way to accept additional param in header?

Answer (score 2):

This way it works

```
'Accept' => '*/*'
```

**Good luck**!

Answer (score 1):

Guzzle 6 removed the `json()` method because of PSR-7 compliance (ref. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1106). So if you're using an earlier version, lowerends' answer may work; for version 6 users, use this instead:

```
$response = GuzzleHttp\post('http://www.example.com:1234/rest/user/validat', [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'],
    'body'    => '{"email":"user@domain.com", "pwd":"xxxxxx"}'
]);
print_r(json_decode($response->getBody(), true));
```

Comment: I am using guzzlehttp/guzzle version 6.3. Getting the response in string format. tried every possible way (json_decode) but still in string format. please help

Answer (score 0):

removing the space between 'Content-Type: application/json' and modify it to 'Content-Type:application/json' worked for me